# 'cl' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run a Qt application which uses MSVC. I have Visual C++ installed and I also have the PATH set for CL, furthermore, whenever I try using cl in a regular command prompt, it works.

However, in QtCreator, when running / debugging my application, I get the following error:

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Users\Censored\Documents\Qt\build-Shard-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\Censored\Documents\Qt\build-Shard-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
11:38:32: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Shard (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
```

And in my Kits tab in my Build & Run, I get this warning when hovering over the Kit I am using for the build:

[image]

I need to use MSVC because I need to use QtWebEngineWidgets. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To state the obvious, you need to either configure Qt Creator, or re-install the beast.

Comment: Is cl in your path?

Answer (score 0):

I got almost the same scenario, except by the debugger that it's installed.
Just install the Windows SDK, for Windows 10 it's [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk).

That CMake warning means that the compiler could not be found by CMake, and I think that the cl.exe will not be found to do the compilation.

I installed the VS and all tools that I need (C++ compiler, Windows SDK 10.0.10586, Tools and Windows SDK) and the problem remained. Then I downloaded the VS 2015 ISO and installed the packages *BuildTools_MSBuildDev12_amd64* and *BuildTools_MSBuildDev12_x86* manually, not by the regular setup, and it works. All warnings was gone and I could compile with MSVC2015.